# Is posible change quasar components design?

Tags: vue.js, themes, quasar

For eg. if you would like to use AdminLTE or similar, but not use default quasar components design?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can create your own components based on design and use it on the Quasar app. You can write raw HTML and CSS.